# joblib.parallel cannot process function that reads csv

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write parallel coding for reading and dealing with trials of data. With correct filepaths corresponding, the code stopped?? at pandas.read_csv. (Similar code worked before. However after I added up some other function in other parts, it didn't.)Besides, there's no error message.

This is under python 2.7, OS system.

This line of code cannot go through

`emd_all_trials = Parallel(n_jobs=total_trialNum,backend='threading')(delayed(initialize_container)(i) for i in range(1, total_trialNum + 1))`,

which refers to
''''

```
def initialize_container(trialNum):
    '
    Initialization of container for input trial
    :param trialNum: int
    :return: a corresponding container for the input trialNum
    '
    # Load pupil data
    y, s, dt, T = pupil_data.load_data(subj, trialNum)
    u, kernel_coef, tau, v = em_algorithm.kernel_convolution_ut(s, u_dim, dt, T)
    G = np.nan
    Q = np.nan
    emd = container.EMData(y, u, u_dim, mu, Sigma, R, Q, G, pupil_data.t_bin)
    emd_all_trials[trialNum - 1] = emd
    return emd
```

''''
and in pupil_data.load_data
''''

```
filepath = "./data/...."+str(subj)+"trial_0"  
data = pd.read_csv(filepath + str(trialNum) + ".csv")
```

''''
it stuck at data = pd.read_csv

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason why it's not working.
Nothing related with code.

I was runing **init**.py file while import **init**.py to pupil_data.py file.